# Subsetting a data.frame with an integer matrix

Tags: r

I keep running into this and am wondering if there's an easy work-around.  For some situations I find it more logical to think about subsetting a matrix in

```
N <- 12
N.NA <- 6
dat <- data.frame(V1=runif(N),V2=runif(N))
sel.mat <- matrix(c(sample(seq(N),N.NA),sample(ncol(dat),N.NA,replace=TRUE)),ncol=2)
```

This works for selection, but not for replacement:

```
> dat[sel.mat]
[1] 0.2582569 0.8455966 0.8828083 0.5384263 0.9574810 0.5623158
> dat[sel.mat] <- NA
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sel.mat, value = NA) : 
  only logical matrix subscripts are allowed in replacement
```

I realize that there's a reason for the error message (it wouldn't know what to do if you had multiple replacements pointing to the same element), but that doesn't stop R from allowing integer replacement on vectors (e.g. `dat$V1[c(2,3)] <- NA`).

Is there a convenient way to allow replacement by integer matrix?

Comment: In the current R-devel snapshot, `dat[sel.mat] <- NA` **is** supported. Matrix indexing with replacement will thus be available from R-3.0.0 on. (See my answer below for more details.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, matrix indexing with replacement **does work** in the current `R-devel` snapshot (and will be a part of `R-3.0.0`). Obviously someone in R-core had the same wish as you did.

As documented in the [R-devel NEWS file](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-devel.html):

> Matrix indexing of dataframes by two-column numeric indices is now supported for replacement as well as extraction.

A demonstration:

```
dat[sel.mat]
## [1] 0.3355509 0.4114056 0.2334332 0.6597042 0.7707762 0.7783584
dat[sel.mat] <- NA
dat[sel.mat]
## [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

R.version.string
# [1] "R Under development (unstable) (2012-12-29 r61478)"
```

Comment: Yeah. They added the code back in October of 2012, and it won't make it into a numbered release until April of 2013, but I suppose that's what good beta testing always looks like!

Answer (score 7):

Convert it to a matrix :

```
dat.m <- as.matrix(dat)
dat.m[sel.mat] <- NA
> dat.m
             V1         V2
 [1,] 0.2539189         NA
 [2,] 0.5216975         NA
 [3,] 0.1206138 0.14714848
 [4,] 0.2841779 0.52352209
 [5,] 0.3965337         NA
 [6,] 0.1871074 0.23747235
 [7,] 0.2991774         NA
 [8,]        NA 0.09509202
 [9,] 0.4636460 0.59384430
[10,] 0.5493738 0.92334630
[11,] 0.7160894         NA
[12,] 0.9568567 0.80398264
```

**Edit** explain why we have an error with data.frame

```
dat.m[sel.mat] <- NA
```

is equivalent to do the following :

```
temp <- dat
dat <- "[<-"(temp, sel.mat, value=NA)

 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(temp, sel.mat, value = NA) : 
 only logical matrix subscripts are allowed in replacement
```

now I can  do the follwing and it works :

```
dat <- "[<-"(as.matrix(temp), sel.mat, value=NA)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create a logical matrix based on the integer matrix:

```
log.mat <- matrix(FALSE, nrow(dat), ncol(dat))
log.mat[sel.mat] <- TRUE
```

This matrix could be used for replacing values in the data frame with `NA` (or other values):

```
is.na(dat) <- log.mat
```

The result:

```
           V1         V2
1  0.76063534         NA
2  0.27713051 0.10593451
3  0.74301263 0.77689458
4  0.42202155         NA
5  0.54563816 0.10233017
6          NA 0.05818723
7  0.83531963 0.93805113
8  0.99316128 0.61505393
9  0.08743757         NA
10 0.95510231 0.51267338
11 0.14035257         NA
12 0.59408022         NA
```

This allows you to keep the original object as data frame allowing columns of different types.

Answer (score 2):

In R, the expressions

```
dat[sel.mat]
dat[sel.mat] <- NA
```

are S3 methods and equivalent to

```
`[.data.frame`(x=dat, i=sel.mat)
`[<-.data.frame`(x=dat, i=sel.mat, value=NA)
```

since `class(dat)` is "data.frame".

You may look into the source code of

```
`[.data.farme`
`[<-.data.frame`
```

and modify it to what you want.

---

In your case, maybe you want:

```
`[<-.data.frame` <- function(x, i, j, value) {
  if (class(i) != "matrix") return(base:::`[<-.data.frame`(x, i, j, value))
  if (class(i[1]) != "integer") return(base:::`[<-.data.frame`(x, i, j, value))
  # check the length of i and value here
  if (length(value) < nrow(i)) {
    if (nrow(i) %% length(value) != 0) warning("some warning message should be here")
    value <- rep(value, nrow(i) %/% length(value) + 1)
  }
  value <- value[1:nrow(i)]
  for(index in 1:nrow(i)) {
    x[i[index,1], i[index,2]] <- value[index]
  }
  return(x)
}
```

try it:

```
N <- 12
N.NA <- 6
dat <- data.frame(V1=runif(N),V2=runif(N))
sel.mat <- matrix(c(sample(seq(N),N.NA),sample(ncol(dat),N.NA,replace=TRUE)),ncol=2)
dat[sel.mat] <- NA
dat
```

Comment: (+1) as well.  Not sure why this didn't get more upvotes other than that rewriting base functions is usually best avoided to avoid confusion.  But it's a nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a loop?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sel.mat))
{
  dat[sel.mat[i,1],sel.mat[i,2]] <- NA
}

> dat
              V1         V2
    1         NA 0.27002155
    2  0.7253383         NA
    3         NA 0.63847293
    4  0.1768720 0.64586587
    5  0.3796935 0.62261843
    6  0.6751365 0.78328647
    7  0.9801140 0.82259732
    8         NA 0.08606641
    9  0.3294625 0.44110121
    10 0.2830957         NA
    11 0.6868594 0.09767882
    12 0.9802349         NA
```