# Elegant way of creating subsets from data.frame and binary matrix

Tags: r, split, binary, subset, sapply

I have a data frame with columns Price and Material, and a true/false matrix with N columns (each column is a particular type of material), and the T/F value denotes if the 'material' string appears in the data matrix

Data

```
Price    Material
2.33     Metal nickel linen cotton
3.45     silver emerald steel
7.45     cotton silk wood
```

Matrix

```
Metal Nickel Linen Cotton Silver Emerald Steel Cotton Silk Wood
T     T      T     T      0      0       0     0      0    0
0     0      0     0      T      T       T     0      0    0
```

...etc.

How do I create a subset the prices based on the material? 
So I can calculate the mean, range mode etc of prices which have the material 'Metal'.

My initial solution was to multiply the

```
newMat<- data$price * materialmatrix.
```

and then perform column operations on newMat (mean, quantile etc.)

But this seems like a brutal way of doing things, as I would like to combine the subsets (e.g average price for something with Metal && Cotton).

I also tried

```
split(data, wsearch, drop=TRUE)
```

but got the warning.

```
Warning message:
  In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...)  
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

Was trying to use `lapply`, `split`, `ddply`, and `subset`, but my understanding of R is not strong enough to execute.

I know this is probably very simple, but I am stuck on how to use the matrix to create multiple subsets, rather than create one subset at a time.

Any help would be great.

I have looked at the following

[Subsetting a data.frame with an integer matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498990/subsetting-a-data-frame-with-an-integer-matrix)

[subsetting matrix with id from another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752049/subsetting-matrix-with-id-from-another-matrix)

[Select observations from a subset to create a new subset based on a large dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543404/select-observations-from-a-subset-to-create-a-new-subset-based-on-a-large-datafr)

[R Selecting column in a data frame by column in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566739/r-selecting-column-in-a-data-frame-by-column-in-another-data-frame)

Comment: It is unclear what the structure of `Data` is. Best would be if you could please provide a reproducible example, e.g. give us the outputs of `dput(Data)` and `dput(Matrix)`.

Comment: @flodel dput(head(data$Price))
c(17, 35, 12, 26, 1.35, 10)
c("linen","wax string metal cube", 
"brass", "linen")

Comment: dput(head(wsearch))
structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, ..........FALSE), .Dim = c(6L, 140L))

Comment: Data is a data.frame and wsearch is a Matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(reshape2)
library(splitstackshape)

# sample data
df <- data.frame(price = c(17, 35, 12, 26, 1.35, 10),
                 material = c("linen",
                              "wax string metal cube",
                              "Metal nickel linen cotton",
                              "brass",
                              "linen",
                              "cotton silk wood"))

# split the concatenated material variable
df2 <- concat.split(data = df, split.col = "material", sep = " ", drop = TRUE)

# replace blanks with NA
df2[df2 == ""] <- NA

# melt data to long format
df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "price", na.rm = TRUE)

# calculate summary stats by material (= 'value' variable)
df4 <- aggregate(price ~ value, data = df3, summary)

#     value price.Min. price.1st Qu. price.Median price.Mean price.3rd Qu. price.Max.
# 1   brass     26.000        26.000       26.000     26.000        26.000     26.000
# 2  cotton     10.000        10.500       11.000     11.000        11.500     12.000
# 3    cube     35.000        35.000       35.000     35.000        35.000     35.000
# 4   linen      1.350         6.675       12.000     10.120        14.500     17.000
# 5   metal     35.000        35.000       35.000     35.000        35.000     35.000
# 6   Metal     12.000        12.000       12.000     12.000        12.000     12.000
# 7  nickel     12.000        12.000       12.000     12.000        12.000     12.000
# 8    silk     10.000        10.000       10.000     10.000        10.000     10.000
# 9  string     35.000        35.000       35.000     35.000        35.000     35.000
# 10    wax     35.000        35.000       35.000     35.000        35.000     35.000
# 11   wood     10.000        10.000       10.000     10.000        10.000     10.000
```

Comment: Winner, Winner Chicken Dinner! I knew Plyr would have the answer, but the melt command scared me a little...this is amazing, with your high score, this is probably tired of praise, but THANK YOU SO MUCH...you saved my weekend;-) Come to Dublin and dinner is on me!

Comment: @conr404, glad to help! Have a nice (R free?) weekend! Cheers.